# reading a file using getc and skipping a line if it starts with semicolon

Tags: c

```
while((c = getc(file)) != -1)
{
    if (c == ';')
    {
        //here I want to skip the line that starts with ;
       //I don't want to read any more characters on this line
    }
    else
    {
            do
            {
                //Here I do my stuff 


            }while (c != -1 && c != '\n');//until end of file
    }
}
```

Can I completely skip a line using getc if first character of line is a semicolon?

Comment: Yes.  What character is at the end of a line?  How do you find it?

Comment: Is there a max-length your lines can have? In that case why not simply use `fgets` and search for the first non-space character in the string to see if it's a semi-colon, and if it is then just continue your reading loop.

Comment: If you don't read the read of the line, how will you find where it ends?

Comment: It could be anything! if line does not start with semicolon then getc would read entire line till next new line and do same thing over and over until EOF. How do I skip that line starting with ; is bugging me.

Comment: In order to skip the line that starts with semicolon, you're going to need to read characters (and not do anything with them) until you see an end-of-line.

Comment: Thought so, but wasn't so sure, maybe it could have a way around it... so probably just read entire file line by line instead of ch by ch... thanks anyways for looking into it

Comment: "*Can I completely skip a line using getc if first character of line is a semicolon?*" if you'd started by 1st coding a function to read a whole line from where the file-pointer points to you could, else you can't. So just start-over ... ;-)

Comment: the function: `getc()` is usually defined as macro that invokes `fgetc()` however, `getc()` evaluates the input stream twice.   Suggest replacing `getc()` with `fgetc()`

Comment: @user3629249: I think you will find that `getc()` seldom calls `fgetc()`.  Rather, the implementation of `fgetc()` is likely to be: `int fgetc(FILE *fp) { return getc(fp); }`.  There is no mandate that `getc()` shall reference the stream twice; it is, however, allowed to reference it more than once (which is unusual and usually not allowed; most macros in the standard C library are not allowed to access their arguments more than once).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  I took my comment straight out of the ubuntu linux 14.04 man page for getc()

Comment: @user3629249: Hmmm...intriguing...on the whole, it's best to cite sources when you quote them (URL is good).  On my machine running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTE, `man getc` says: _`getc()` is equivalent to `fgetc()` except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates `stream` more than once_ which is in turn a quote from the C standard (the 1999 and 2011 standards add _'so the argument should never be an expression with side effects'_).  That does not say what you say the manual says on your machine.

Answer (score 4):

Your code contains a couple of references to `-1`.  I suspect that you're assuming that `EOF` is `-1`.  That's a common value, but it is simply required to be a negative value — any negative value that will fit in an `int`.  Do not get into bad habits at the start of your career.  Write `EOF` where you are checking for `EOF` (and don't write `EOF` where you are checking for `-1`).

```
int c;

while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ';')
    {
        // Gobble the rest of the line, or up until EOF
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF && c != '\n')
            ;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            //Here I do my stuff
            …
        } while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF && c != '\n');
    }
}
```

Note that `getc()` returns an `int` so `c` is declared as an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that by "line" you mean a string of characters until you hit a designated end-of-line character (here assumed as `\n`, different systems use different characters or character sequences like `\r\n`). Then whether the current character `c` is in a semicolon-started line or not becomes a state information which you need to maintain across different iterations of the `while`-loop. For example:

```
bool is_new_line = true;
bool starts_with_semicolon = false;
int c;
while ((c = getc(file) != EOF) {
  if (is_new_line) {
    starts_with_semicolon = c == ';'; 
  }
  if (!starts_with_semicolon) {
    // Process the character.
  }
  // If c is '\n', then next letter starts a new line.
  is_new_line = c == '\n';
}
```

The code is just to illustrate the principle -- it's not tested or anything.

Comment: I see where your idea goes, will try that and let you know, thanks for sharing.